# Get the Number of 5 Reviews from Total Number of Reviews in Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm pretty new to react and node, and I'm working on a project where I'm creating a review component for a product. I am trying to get the number of 5 star reviews out of the total number of reviews. I have been trying to do this in my backend in my productRouter.js document by finding the reviews with 5 stars and then finding the length of that constant. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, and I would really appreciate any help or advice on ow to do this. Thank you.

What I have so far:

```
const num5 = product.reviews.rating
const newValue5 = num5.find((number)=> number === 5 );
product.numRating5 = newValue5.length;
```

Rest of productRouter.js

```
import express from 'express';
import expressAsyncHandler from 'express-async-handler';
import data from '../data.js';
import Product from '../models/productModel.js';
import { isAdmin, isAuth, isSellerOrAdmin } from '../utils.js';

const productRouter = express.Router();

productRouter.get(
  '/',
 expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
 /* const products = await Product.find({});*/
  const name = req.query.name || '';
  const category = req.query.category || '';
  res.send(products);
  })
);

productRouter.get(
  '/categories',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const categories = await Product.find().distinct('category');
    res.send(categories);
  })
);

productRouter.get(
  '/slug',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const slug = await Product.find().distinct('slug');
    res.send(slug);
  })
);

productRouter.get(
  '/seed',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // await Product.remove({});
    const createdProducts = await Product.insertMany(data.products);
    res.send({ createdProducts });
  })
);



productRouter.get(
  '/:id',
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
    if (product) {
      res.send(product);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
    }
  })
);
productRouter.post(
    '/',
    isAuth,
    isSellerOrAdmin,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const product = new Product({
        name: 'sample name ' + Date.now(),
        rating: 0, 
      });
      const createdProduct = await product.save();
      res.send({ message: 'Product Created', product: createdProduct });
    })
  );


  
  productRouter.delete(
    '/:id',
    isAuth,
    isAdmin,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id);
      if (product) {
        const deleteProduct = await product.remove();
        res.send({ message: 'Product Deleted', product: deleteProduct });
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
      }
    })
  );


  productRouter.post(
    '/:id/reviews',
    isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
      const productId = req.params.id;
      const product = await Product.findById(productId);
      if (product) {
        if (product.reviews.find((x) => x.name === req.user.name)) {
          return res
            .status(400)
            .send({ message: 'You already submitted a review' });
        }
        const review = {
          name: req.user.name,
          rating: Number(req.body.rating),
          comment_title: req.body.comment_title,
          comment: req.body.comment,
          age: req.body.age,
          customerImages: req.body.customerImages,
        };
        product.reviews.push(review);
        product.numReviews = product.reviews.length;
        product.rating =
          product.reviews.reduce((a, c) => a = a +c.rating, 0) /
          product.reviews.length;

        

        const updatedProduct = await product.save();
        res.status(201).send({
          message: 'Review Created',
          review: updatedProduct.reviews[updatedProduct.reviews.length - 1],
        });
      } else {
        res.status(404).send({ message: 'Product Not Found' });
      }
    })
  );
  



  
export default productRouter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const newArr = oldArr.filter((this) => this.rating === 5)
console.log(newArr.length) // Amount of 5 star reviews.
```

newArr is a new array,
oldArr is your current array,
this.rating can be replaced by whatever the value is in the object or value if it's just a list of values, feel free to comment if you need help.